# Configure login page with firebase database

Tags: angular, ngx-admin

I am using ngx-admin and so far i have been able to create the required pages that will be shown on the dashboard but now i am trying to configure the auth module in such a way that on startup the login page will be shown to the user and after logging in the user will be redirected to the dashboard page but the auth module is created in the nebular theme and all the files are declaration files there e.g `auth.module.d.ts` because of this d in these files i am unable to write any function there and i also need to configure the login with firebase so far i have been able to show the login page on the startup but now i need to configure these files to start communicating with firebase server and login starts working. I have already installed firebase packages that were necessary. So now i am not sure how and where do i need to create the services
Here are some of my auth module files

auth.component.d.ts

```
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { NbAuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
export declare class NbAuthComponent implements OnDestroy {
    protected auth: NbAuthService;
    protected location: Location;
    private alive;
    subscription: any;
    authenticated: boolean;
    token: string;
    constructor(auth: NbAuthService, location: Location);
    back(): boolean;
    ngOnDestroy(): void;
}
```

login.component.d.ts

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NbAuthSocialLink } from '../../auth.options';
import { NbAuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
export declare class NbLoginComponent {
    protected service: NbAuthService;
    protected options: {};
    protected cd: ChangeDetectorRef;
    protected router: Router;
    redirectDelay: number;
    showMessages: any;
    strategy: string;
    errors: string[];
    messages: string[];
    user: any;
    submitted: boolean;
    socialLinks: NbAuthSocialLink[];
    rememberMe: boolean;
    constructor(service: NbAuthService, options: {}, cd: ChangeDetectorRef, router: Router);
    login(): void;
    getConfigValue(key: string): any;
}
```

auth.service.d.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { NbAuthStrategy } from '../strategies/auth-strategy';
import { NbAuthResult } from './auth-result';
import { NbTokenService } from './token/token.service';
import { NbAuthToken } from './token/token';
/**
 * Common authentication service.
 * Should be used to as an interlayer between UI Components and Auth Strategy.
 */
export declare class NbAuthService {
    protected tokenService: NbTokenService;
    protected strategies: any;
    constructor(tokenService: NbTokenService, strategies: any);
    /**
     * Retrieves current authenticated token stored
     * @returns {Observable<any>}
     */
    getToken(): Observable<NbAuthToken>;
    /**
     * Returns true if auth token is present in the token storage
     * @returns {Observable<boolean>}
     */
    isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean>;
    /**
     * Returns true if valid auth token is present in the token storage.
     * If not, calls the strategy refreshToken, and returns isAuthenticated() if success, false otherwise
     * @returns {Observable<boolean>}
     */
    isAuthenticatedOrRefresh(): Observable<boolean>;
    /**
     * Returns tokens stream
     * @returns {Observable<NbAuthSimpleToken>}
     */
    onTokenChange(): Observable<NbAuthToken>;
    /**
     * Returns authentication status stream
     * @returns {Observable<boolean>}
     */
    onAuthenticationChange(): Observable<boolean>;
    /**
     * Authenticates with the selected strategy
     * Stores received token in the token storage
     *
     * Example:
     * authenticate('email', {email: 'email@example.com', password: 'test'})
     *
     * @param strategyName
     * @param data
     * @returns {Observable<NbAuthResult>}
     */
    authenticate(strategyName: string, data?: any): Observable<NbAuthResult>;
    /**
     * Registers with the selected strategy
     * Stores received token in the token storage
     *
     * Example:
     * register('email', {email: 'email@example.com', name: 'Some Name', password: 'test'})
     *
     * @param strategyName
     * @param data
     * @returns {Observable<NbAuthResult>}
     */
    register(strategyName: string, data?: any): Observable<NbAuthResult>;
    /**
     * Sign outs with the selected strategy
     * Removes token from the token storage
     *
     * Example:
     * logout('email')
     *
     * @param strategyName
     * @returns {Observable<NbAuthResult>}
     */
    logout(strategyName: string): Observable<NbAuthResult>;
    /**
     * Sends forgot password request to the selected strategy
     *
     * Example:
     * requestPassword('email', {email: 'email@example.com'})
     *
     * @param strategyName
     * @param data
     * @returns {Observable<NbAuthResult>}
     */
    requestPassword(strategyName: string, data?: any): Observable<NbAuthResult>;
    /**
     * Tries to reset password with the selected strategy
     *
     * Example:
     * resetPassword('email', {newPassword: 'test'})
     *
     * @param strategyName
     * @param data
     * @returns {Observable<NbAuthResult>}
     */
    resetPassword(strategyName: string, data?: any): Observable<NbAuthResult>;
    /**
     * Sends a refresh token request
     * Stores received token in the token storage
     *
     * Example:
     * refreshToken('email', {token: token})
     *
     * @param {string} strategyName
     * @param data
     * @returns {Observable<NbAuthResult>}
     */
    refreshToken(strategyName: string, data?: any): Observable<NbAuthResult>;
    /**
     * Get registered strategy by name
     *
     * Example:
     * getStrategy('email')
     *
     * @param {string} provider
     * @returns {NbAbstractAuthProvider}
     */
    protected getStrategy(strategyName: string): NbAuthStrategy;
    private processResultToken;
}
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "--------------------------------------",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://----------.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxx-bde65",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  }
};
```

P.S. If there is too much code that i need to write then you can explain me how i need to write but if you can help me with a little bit of then that would be awesome too.

Answer (score 0):

you have to override the current template. Follow the instruction provided here.

https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/